# Não consigo pegar o valor de um objeto dentro de uma ARRAY

Tags: javascript, json, intel-xdk, cordova-plugin

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para ler uma base wordpress. Tenho muitos posts que estão separados por categoria.

Ja consegui mostrar na view as categorias mas quando seleciono alguma categoria especifica ele mostra todas as fotos de todas as categorias.

Estou anexando duas imagens para melhor explicar do console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira pesquisa foi simples pois pego pelo JSON API pelas categorias mas quando clico em alguma que estou perdido. Segue os codigos.

Preciso muito da ajuda de vocês. Trabalho com crianças com ELA (Exclerose Amiotrofica lateral). Este projeto tem a função de unir as pessoas com esse problema.

Codigo que pega as categorias e lista:

```
<blink> 
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Carregando...', duration: 3000});
    $http.get('localhost/app/api/get_tag_posts/…{ 
        $scope.lista = data; 
        console.log(data); 
        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
    }).error(function(erro){ 
        console.log(erro); 
        $ionicLoading.hide(); 
    }); 
</blink>
```

Depois eu pego em uma div e mostro:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="pega in lista.posts"> </BR> 
    <a href="#/app/search" ng-click="obras($index)">
        <img src="{{pega.thumbnail}}" width="300" height="200"> 
    </a> 
    <h4> {{pega.title}} </h4> 
</div>
```

Aqui está o problema, pois quando eu escolho a categoria eu tenho que pegar as imagens dentro dessa pesquisa e está me mostrando tudo:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="pega in lista.posts"> 
    <div ng-repeat="pega2 in pega.attachments"> 
        <div class="Item item-text-wrap"> 
            <img src="{{pega2.url}}" width="100%"> <p></p> 
            <a class="button button-small button-outline button-positive" ng-click="Compartilhar($index)">Compartilhar...</a> <p></p> </br> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Roger, você pode colocar o código que lista as categorias e o que trata quando essa categoria é selecionada?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda vou tentar colocar aqui. Não sei como insiro imagem novamente. estou tentando

Comment: Você pode colar o código, selecionar ele e pressionar CTRL + K para indentar.

Comment: Quando pressiono CTRL+K ele abre o navegador para pesquisar. Não consigo. Me desculpe. Me ajude por favor.

Comment: Ao invés de apertar CTRL + K, tenta selecionar o texto todo quando você colar na edição e clicar no ícone com chaves `{ }`.

Comment: Codigo que pega as categorias e lista

<blink>
$ionicLoading.show({template: 'Carregando...', duration: 3000}); 
$http.get('http://localhost/app/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=cibelle-costa').success(function(data){
$scope.lista = data;
console.log(data);
$ionicLoading.hide();
}).error(function(erro){
console.log(erro);
$ionicLoading.hide();
});
</blink?

Comment: depois eu pego em uma div e mostro

<div class="card" ng-repeat="pega in lista.posts">
   </BR>
    <a href="#/app/search" ng-click="obras($index)"><img src="{{pega.thumbnail}}" width="300" height="200"> </a>
      <h4> {{pega.title}} </h4>

  </div>

Comment: Aqui está o problema pois quando eu escolho a categoria eu tenho que pegar as imagens dentro dessa pesquisa e está me mostrando tudo

<div class="card" ng-repeat="pega in lista.posts">
   <div ng-repeat="pega2 in pega.attachments"> 
    <div class="Item item-text-wrap">
     <img src="{{pega2.url}}" width="100%">
     <p></p>
     <a class="button button-small button-outline button-positive" ng-click="Compartilhar($index)">Compartilhar...</a>
     <p></p>
     </br>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: desculpe mas não consegui colocar de outra forma. Agradeço demais sua ajuda.

Comment: Eu percebi que você tá usando o mesmo nome de variável 2x, que é a `pega`, será que ela não tá dando conflito? tenta alterar um dos ng-repeat para ver `pega3` pra ver se vai funcionar.

Comment: não funcionou. Como faço para consultar um array que está dentro de outro atraves do indice que tenho? Voce pode me passar um codigo disso por favor?