# Como fazer consulta ng-repeat com varios arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um blog e preciso pegar a url das imagens de cada post. Só que estão dentro dos arrays e não estou conseguindo.

A imagem ilustra o caminho. Alguem pode me ajudar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os pontos em vermelhos mostram. Tenho 3 posts e no post1 tenho 9 imagens anexadas.

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: Qual seu javascript e html até agora? Mostrando-os fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Veja as consultas aqui
[link]
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174240/n%C3%A3o-consigo-pegar-o-valor-de-um-objeto-dentro-de-uma-array
[link]

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve criar um ng-repeat para pegar os posts, dentro deste ng-repeat você deve criar outro para pegar os attachments com as url's, segue o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  
  
  $scope.meuObjeto = {count: 3, pages: 1, posts:
                      [{ attachments: 
                          [
                            {
                              id: 1,
                              caption: 'Teste caption',
                              description: 'Teste description',
                              url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'
                            },
                            {
                              id: 2,
                              caption: 'Teste caption 1',
                              description: 'Teste description1',
                              url: 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
                            }
                          ],
                        outroAtributo : 'Teste outro atributo'
                        
                      },
                      { attachments: 
                          [
                            {
                              id: 3,
                              caption: 'Teste caption2',
                              description: 'Teste description2',
                              url: 'http://www.google.com/'
                            }
                          ],
                        outroAtributo : 'Teste outro atributo'
                        
                      },
                      ]
                     };
              
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in meuObjeto.posts track by $index">
      {{$index}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="att in post.attachments track by att.id">{{att.url}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo você pode me passar um email ou contato para que eu posso te explicar. É um trabalho social e preciso muito resolver isso. Conto com sua ajuda.